# Javascript alert boxes? How do I make an event upon clicking "ok" and "cancel"?

Tags: javascript

Yes, this is homework. I completed the assignment in it's entirety. Just need to make an alert box for when the player finishes the game and wins.

If the user clicks "OK", then the confirm box will disappear, and a new random board will be displayed, as if "Start a New Game" was clicked.

If the user clicks "Cancel", then the confirm box will disappear, and the display will remain with the tiles in the winning position, same as when the page was initially loaded. The user may click "Start a New Game" to start a new game.

LINK to the actual assignment: http://www.eveo.org/tiles/ver2
JAVASCRIPT file link: http://www.eveo.org/tiles/ver2/game.js

I'm not looking in changing anything else, just need this alert box problem fixed. So far I have (in pseudo code):

```
if win = true
   confirm box ("You won! Congratulations! Would you like another game?")
upon pressing OK: board randomized
upon cancel: nothing happens, used needs to click "start a new game"
```

Comment: looks you already solved it, what's the question?

Comment: What about confirmation box instead of alert?

Comment: you can use dialog box plugin of jquery. It looks much better than ordinary javascript box. dialog box provides both the events cancel or ok. Check the below link for more information http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: Dangit, that was the wrong code. I just updated with pseudo code. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` goes in `switch`, `for` and `while` constructs only. Don't put it anywhere else. If you don't want to do anything on `else`, either leave it empty or just remove it altogether.

```
if (confirm("You won! Congratulations! Would you like another game?")) {
    initialize();
}
```

Comment: Omitting curly braces is not a practice that should be encouraged (at least not at this level) since it's just like *asking* for errors/bugs to be introduced.

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer to fit your new question's requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Wait, it's that simple? So my entire code would be:

    `if (confirm("You won! Congratulations! Would you like another game?")) {
        initialize();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var confirmer = confirm("Wish to accept or Cancel?");

if(confirmer){
    // Do stuff on OK
    initialize();
}else{
    // Do other stuff on cancel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are *almost* there:

```
if (confirm("Wish to accept or Cancel")) {
    if (confirm(("You won! Congratulations! Would you like another game?")) {
        initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch`

Comment: @Delan Azabani - yup, removed the broken and redundant `else`.